# Can not use theme watch for my shopify store

Tags: shopify

Everytime I tried command "theme watch" it sent me this error:

> [development] This is the live theme on Nhan's test store. If you wish
> to make changes to it, then you will have to pass the --allow-live
> flag cannot make changes to a live theme without an override

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just have to add `--allow-live` at the end of theme watch. So the full command should be:

```
theme watch --allow-live
```

Answer (score 0):

using the simply flag:

```
--allow-live
```

does not explain why use that flag is necessary, actually this is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66939520/allow-live-terminal-command-for-shopify-development).

I report main information:

"The --allow-live is used only when you are working on a live theme.

If you don't want to use the --allow-live you must create a development theme and work on that, then the flag will not be required."