# --allow-live terminal command for shopify development

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line, shopify, liquid

So while using "themekit" in vs code terminal, I get the following message:

> "This is the live theme on my-store. If you wish to make changes to it, then you will have to pass the --allow-live flag"

and to resolve it, I add --allow-live flag to the command and it works fine.(as described in the other answer on stack overflow)

BUT, while it did resolve the issue, everytime I try to use theme watch or theme deploy, it repeatedly asks me to use the --allow-live flag.

While researching themekit on google, youtube and other tutorials, I saw that it works fine for other developers even if they don't use --allow-live.

I read the following shopify documentation as well- https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/checksums

How is "theme watch --allow-live" different from the "theme watch" command, and how do I make sure that everytime I use themekit, it doesn't ask me to add the flag. Is there a way by which it automatically allows live changes without manually adding the flag everytime I try using themekit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--allow-live` is used only when you are working on a live theme.

If you don't want to use the `--allow-live` you must create a development theme and work on that, then the flag will not be required.

Please note that this flag was added recently (a few months back) so it's possible that you are reading older documentation where this flag was not present.

The flag cannot be stopped on a live theme, this is a prevention rule so that you don't overwrite the live theme without knowing that you are working on it.

So `theme watch` and `theme watch --allow-live` do the exactly same thing, but the second one just allows for the modification on the live theme.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now.